# Prestashop 1.7 on FreeNAS 9.10 Cannot Connect to Database Server via browser

Tags: php, mysql, database, freebsd, prestashop-1.7

### Scenario

I am attempting to install Prestashop 1.7 on a local FreeNAS server, so that I can have a development environment to design and test custom modules before applying them to my live remote-hosted instance of Prestashop.  I get to the database connection stage of the installation process, and receive this error:

> Database Server is not found. Please verify the login, password and server fields (DbPDO)

### Steps Taken

To ensure all was setup properly, I ran the following queries on the MySQL console:

```
CREATE DATABASE 'prestashop'
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1
    COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
CREATE USER 'adminuser'@'%'
    IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.*
    TO 'adminuser'@'%'
    WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I understand the security implications of granting all privileges on all databases to a user from anywhere, but I did it this way temporarily for testing in a closed environment (i.e. no WAN access).  In my browser during the system configuration stage of the install process, I entered the following for the database configuration form:

- Database server address: ***[IP address of the MySQL server]***
- Database name: **prestashop**
- Database login: **adminuser**
- Database password: **password**
- Tables prefix: **ps_**

This generates the same error as before.  I am able to establish a connection to the MySQL server using `dbForge Studio Express for MySQL` using the same criteria.  From this, I know that my connection details are correct, but that for whatever reason, `Prestashop` cannot connect.

### Environment

Here are stats for my environment that may be useful in determining the cause:

- Server OS: FreeNAS 9.10.2

  - In a FreeBSD jail
- DB Server: MySQL 5.6.39
- Web Server: Apache 2.4.29
- PHP Server: PHP 5.6.33

### Considerations

I have searched (i.e. googled) extensively, and mostly all the causes found were by folks accidentally entering errant parameters.  This is not my case, as I have tested the parameters with `dbForge`.

### Questions

1. What is causing this issue?
2. What steps have I missed in trying to resolve this issue?
3. Is there any pertinent information I am missing which could help solve the issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing I can think of is that you're entering the wrong IP address.

If you're connecting to database remotely with app, then yes you connect with proper IP but if your Apache/PHP server is running in the same environment as MySQL server then the server address should be `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.